# How to write For Update inside Execute Immediate block in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle

I have  a code block like this:

```
SELECT AF INTO JC FROM I_EAggr WHERE Name = 'SED' for Update ;
```

Here, I_EAggr table will be dynamically called and client specific Name column will be there in all client schemas.

Now I need to write this inside Execute Immediate.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

```
SQL> create table I_EAggr(name varchar2(16), af number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into I_EAggr values ('SED', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      vSQL           VARCHAR2(1000);
  3      vName          VARCHAR2(16) := 'SED';
  4      vTableName     VARCHAR2(16) := 'I_EAGGR';
  5      vAF            VARCHAR2(16);
  6  BEGIN
  7      vSQL    := 'select af from ' || vTableName || ' where name = ''' || vName || ''' for update';
  8
  9      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL INTO vAF;
 10  END;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am getting error due to  ''' for update'..it is taking for update as command but the next lines it is not able to identify as SQL commands.          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQL INTO JC;...If I make it as '''' for update' [four single quotes]  the next commands it is identifying but for update gets errored out!

Comment: I can't fully understand; please post your actual code and the error you're having

Comment: Basically  this line after the vSQL, is getting errored out! The compile error is:Error(79,119): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return returning <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk member submultiset The symbol " " was ignored.

Comment: This is how my actual function is: